# include file in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, linux

Is it possible to include a .htaccess in another .htaccess file.  The purpose would be to have a single location of all .htaccess.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 4):

It seems it's not possible.

But you could use any htaccess rules in httpd conf VirtualHost or Directory conext, where includes are possible.

E.g.:

```
<Directory /var/www/site1/>
   <...>
   Include /etc/apache/conf.d/site1-htaccess.inc
</Directory>
```

See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include

Comment: But would not that require an apache restart

Comment: No, it would require reload (graceful restart - no connections aborted). If you need grant reload rights to non-privileged users, you could use sudo.

Comment: Which is exactly I dont want to do.  If I do require, I have to restart apache via a php page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, Apache will check for an .htaccess file in every directory above the current one where AllowOverride is set to something other than None.

This means if your DocumentRoot for a site is /var/www/hello/, and it's serving a request for /path/name/filename, it will check for:
/.htaccess
/var/.htaccess
/var/www/.htaccess
/var/www/hello/.htaccess
/var/www/hello/path/.htaccess
/var/www/hello/path/name/.htaccess

So if you like, you can use a single .htaccess file in your server's DocumentRoot, or even above that to affect multiple sites, as long as AllowOverride allows it for that directory.

Comment: And it will combine all that match?

Comment: @nafg Yes, any directives found in a later .htaccess file should take precedence over what's in the earlier ones, provided the server's AllowOverride for that directory permits it.